# Send email via Google Sheets whenever column contains "Ready"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to automatically send emails via Google Sheets when a column contains a specific value. Below is a dummmy sheet that mimics the cells.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PDqbujeTdClVgArm8uMb2wuONETOxByTtmQz1cx806Y/edit?usp=sharing

I'd like to send an email to contact (Column B) with subject (Column C) and message (Column D) whenever Column E is labeled "Ready"

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While links to external resources might be helpful, questions on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please briefly describe the relevant parts or your spreadsheet and add some sample data directly into the question body. Also show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

#### Send Email Every Hour

```
function sendEmail() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[4] == "Ready") {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(r[1],r[2],r[3]);
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue(`Sent ${new Date()}`)
    }
  });
}
```

Run this at least once:

```
function createTrigger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction()== "sendEmail").filter(e => e).length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail").timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  }
}
```